# Como obtener todos los datos de una potografía con php en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, imagen, macos

Tengo varios días con este problema. Necesito obtener la información de una fotografía, especialmente "Título del proyecto" y "Palabras clave" (como se muestra en la siguiente imagen) que fue editada en una Mac, mi servidor es linux (ubuntu) con laravel 9 y una versión 7 de php. Ya intente de todo y los métodos que mas obtienen información de las imágenes es con php nativo y con una librería (image:make) ambos me traen los mismos datos pero no logro obtener esta información que necesito. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo los codigos a continuación junto con el json que obtengo.

Este es con el método exif_read_data de php:

```
public function getInfo($id)
    {
        try {
            $modelo = new Images();
            $imagen = DB::table('images')->where('id', $id)->first();
            $modelo->get_titule(public_path($imagen->image_path));
            if ($imagen->image_info == null || $imagen->image_with == 0 || $imagen->image_height == 0) {
                $data = getimagesize(public_path($imagen->image_path), $i);
                if ($data) {
                    DB::table('images')->where('id', $id)->update([
                        'image_with' => $data[0],
                        'image_height' => $data[1],
                    ]);
                }
                $info = exif_read_data(public_path($imagen->image_path), 0, true);
                if ($info) {
                    DB::table('images')->where('id', $id)->update([
                        'image_info' => json_encode($info),
                    ]);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            dd($th);
            //throw $th;
        }
    }
```

Información obtenida:

```
"FILE": {
  "FileName": "image68957069_.jpg",
  "FileDateTime": 1687840581,
  "FileSize": 1394395,
  "FileType": 2,
  "MimeType": "image\/jpeg",
  "SectionsFound": "ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF, GPS, INTEROP"
},
"COMPUTED": {
  "html": "width=\"3532\" height=\"5298\"",
  "Height": 5298,
  "Width": 3532,
  "IsColor": 1,
  "ByteOrderMotorola": 0,
  "CCDWidth": "13mm",
  "ApertureFNumber": "f\/5.6",
  "Copyright": "NOMBRE_EMPRESA",
  "Thumbnail.FileType": 2,
  "Thumbnail.MimeType": "image\/jpeg"
},
"IFD0": {
  "ImageWidth": 4160,
  "ImageLength": 6240,
  "BitsPerSample": [
    8,
    8,
    8
  ],
  "PhotometricInterpretation": 2,
  "ImageDescription": "Descripción de la foto",
  "Make": "Canon",
  "Model": "Canon EOS 6D Mark II",
  "Orientation": 1,
  "SamplesPerPixel": 3,
  "XResolution": "720000\/10000",
  "YResolution": "720000\/10000",
  "ResolutionUnit": 2,
  "Software": "Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 (Macintosh)",
  "DateTime": "2023:06:26 16:44:36",
  "Artist": "NOMBRE EMPRESA",
  "WhitePoint": "48320\/154377",
  "PrimaryChromaticities": "16\/25",
  "YCbCrCoefficients": [
    "299\/1000",
    "587\/1000",
    "114\/1000"
  ],
  "YCbCrPositioning": 1,
  "Copyright": "NOMBRE_EMPRESA",
  "Exif_IFD_Pointer": 588,
  "GPS_IFD_Pointer": 1256
},
"THUMBNAIL": {
  "Compression": 6,
  "XResolution": "72\/1",
  "YResolution": "72\/1",
  "ResolutionUnit": 2,
  "JPEGInterchangeFormat": 1370,
  "JPEGInterchangeFormatLength": 5336
},
"EXIF": {
  "ExposureTime": "1\/160",
  "FNumber": "28\/5",
  "ExposureProgram": 1,
  "ISOSpeedRatings": 800,
  "UndefinedTag:0x8830": 2,
  "UndefinedTag:0x8832": 800,
  "ExifVersion": "0230",
  "DateTimeOriginal": "2023:06:26 14:59:06",
  "DateTimeDigitized": "2023:06:26 14:59:06",
  "ComponentsConfiguration": "\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0000",
  "ShutterSpeedValue": "59\/8",
  "ApertureValue": "5\/1",
  "ExposureBiasValue": "0\/1",
  "MaxApertureValue": "55440\/19601",
  "MeteringMode": 5,
  "Flash": 9,
  "FocalLength": "150\/1",
  "SubSecTimeOriginal": "17",
  "FlashPixVersion": "0100",
  "ColorSpace": 65535,
  "ExifImageWidth": 3532,
  "ExifImageLength": 5298,
  "InteroperabilityOffset": 1224,
  "FocalPlaneXResolution": "1248000\/187",
  "FocalPlaneYResolution": "3366979\/501",
  "FocalPlaneResolutionUnit": 2,
  "CustomRendered": 0,
  "ExposureMode": 1,
  "WhiteBalance": 1,
  "SceneCaptureType": 0,
  "UndefinedTag:0xA430": null,
  "UndefinedTag:0xA431": "072051000547",
  "UndefinedTag:0xA432": [
    "70\/1",
    "200\/1",
    "0\/1",
    "0\/1"
  ],
  "UndefinedTag:0xA434": "EF70-200mm f\/2.8L USM",
  "UndefinedTag:0xA435": "0000000000",
  "UndefinedTag:0xA500": "11\/5"
},
"GPS": {
  "GPSVersion": "\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0000"
},
"INTEROP": {
  "InterOperabilityIndex": "R03",
  "InterOperabilityVersion": "0100"
}
```